# Linq To Sql Memory Usage

Tags: vb.net, linq

The scenario is this:
Using the Linq to Sql Classes ... I now have a `DataClasses1DataContext` 
Everything works perfect ... I love it.
In my current setup in my Winforms app I have the following:

```
Using testdata As DataClasses1DataContext = New DataClasses1DataContext
....
...

End using
```

When I break after `Using testdata`, it contains all rows from the table. Is this by design? Obviously, later on I run Linq queries on it ... which are much smaller but how can I avoid all the memory overhead with the whole DB loaded? Clearly I'm missing something.
Thanks
-TD

Comment: Are you sure, that all rows are there by default, or are you enumerating results within Visual Studios debugger?

Comment: Well good point , and I wondered that too, but based on the memory usage I see in Task Manager it looks to not be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was looking to close at Diagnostics in Visual Studio.
After further review it seems to be normal.

Comment: To be clear - "viewing" the tables in the debugger causes the underlying query to execute so that you see all of the rows.  In "normal" execution, only the data that you've queried will be stored in the context.